# Fails to bundle install Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my problem:

```
D:\Rails\Simple-Blog>bundle install

The system cannot find the path specified
```

I use Windows system

Ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

Gem version ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

Rails  version 5.1.3

So when I want to install any gem I just write this command line `gem install` because the `bundle install` doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the `bundler` gem installed, or at least not on your current path. `bundle` is not part of the Ruby install.

```
gem install bundler
```